# Install needed to connect to RabbitMQ from PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Ubuntu 12 server running and I need to run some PHP code on it to connect to RabbitMQ(running on another server - Windows) What is required? If I go to the Ubuntu terminal and run: "which amqp" it returns nothing but if I do: "pecl install amqp" I get:"pecl/amqp is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.9"

What did I do wrong? How do I install amqp and subsequently the librabbitmq client library?

Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first page of google search results:
http://blog.webgen.hu/rabbitmq-for-php-on-ubuntu/

They install the full server on ubuntu, but you don't have to use it after the install, and you can always work on streamlining once you get stuff working.

Answer (score 0):

Amqp is not a command line program, it's a library to access RabbitMQ so `which amqp` won't give you anything.

If you installed the pecl/amqp extension, then you need to use it in your PHP code.

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the "which" - I am new to Linux and PHP so I make mistakes. Ok, is there a way to get all installed extensions so that I can confirm that it installed correctly?

If it is actually installed, can I use "$cnn = new AMQPConnection();" (from http://php.net/manual/en/amqp.examples.php) in my php files?

Answer (score 0):

There is an AMQP native PHP and a C Library + PHP Module implementation which can be use for connection to RabbitMQ.
The Problem they are both really slow compared to python and C# because they do not use connection pooling. 
The PHP implementation is of course the worst.

I worked around the performance issue using Unix Sockets to sent the message to python process(es) writing them to the rabbitmq. Works perfect - approved by load tests

Cheers